# How to use a JSON API?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, api

I know this is probably a bit to "large" question to ask, but I have this JSON API I want to use and I have never used an API before and don't exactly know how to use it, I have read a bit on how to use JSON APIs and also tried around a bit so I have a vague idea of how to use it, but I cant get it to work.

So now to the question If I wanted to create a "ticker" of the last/latest price using this API: https://github.com/ralphtheninja/goxstream

https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming

How would I do that?

I know I'm probably stretching my luck trying to get this question answered, but I have tried for a bit to long now and I'm not really getting anywhere, so would really appreciate all help I can get.

EDIT:
CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="index.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">

var ticker = require('goxtick')('USD')

ticker.on('ticker', function (data) {
  window.alert('ticker data:', data)
})

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't your second link contain a complete example of a ticker program in the "Examples" section?

Comment: If you're tried something please post the code so we can help identify what you're doing wrong

Comment: Ok have posted some code now, didn't at first because I wanted to try to avoid looking completely stupid x)

Comment: You look much smarter for posting code, even if the code isn't perfect!

Comment: Are you trying to use the MtGOX API, or the client library for that API from that GitHub link? An "API" is a bunch of HTTP URLs that return JSON. A library would wrap AJAX requests to that API in something nicer to use. There's not much to explain about using **a** JSON API, you make HTTP requests to it and you get stuff back. How to accomplish a given task with it is something else completely.

Comment: (That said, it seems the MtGOX one is a streaming API based on websockets or socket.io, which is something a bit different in that you probably don't make AJAX requests to it but just handle stuff coming down the pipe as it arrives.)

Comment: Actually, wait a second, that GitHub library is for Node.js. You can't use that in the browser.

Comment: I just want to get the latest price for an simple iPhone html 5 price alarm app I'm making, so don't know whats the best method is, but updated the code again to something that I think is more correct / closer to what I'm trying to do. So I first download the library from GitHub then have that in the same folder as the index.html file?

The website/iPhone app:
http://www.patan77.com/BitcoinPriceAlarm/

Comment: Near as I can tell, you don't "get" the latest price using the streaming API. You get ticker updates pushed to you. You probably want the ticker API which works the way I mentioned before: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1#Multi_Currency_Ticker

Comment: You probably want the ticker API which works the way I mentioned In fact, if you open http://data.mtgox.com/api/2/BTCUSD/money/ticker, you'll get a chunk of JSON with the exchange rate data. Poke around the other pages under https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the mtgox script and jquery you can open a socket and get the price pushed to you like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Price Ticker?</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="http://socketio.mtgox.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
$(
function(){
    var conn = io.connect('http://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox');
    conn.on('message', function(data) {
        // Handle incoming data object.
        $("#price").html(data.depth.price);
    });
}
);
</script>
</head>

<body>


Price: <div id="price">???</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, I just changed "depth" to "trade" and now its exactly what I wanted (:

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I went about getting some information from this API:

1. Read at least part of the documentation.  The **[link](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/Streaming)** you supplied seemed to have enough information to work with.
2. Notice a helpful bit of sample browser code, namely this

   ```
   <script src="https://socketio.mtgox.com/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script>
       var conn = io.connect('https://socketio.mtgox.com/mtgox');
       conn.on('message', function(data) {
           // Handle incoming data object.
       });
   </script>
   ```
3. Create a test HTML page containing nothing but that (on a local webserver, not accessed through file URLs.)
4. Realize that I would actually need to know something's happening, so replace the commented line with a simple

   ```
           console.log(data);
   ```
5. Open this up in the browser, with the developer tools open.
6. Note that nothing happens, but in the Network tab there is an issue loading the resources requested.
7. Attempt to open those resources directly in the browser, notice that the SSL certificate seems to be broken.  Change both from `https` to `http`, just to see if it works.
8. Reload the browser, and watch data scroll by in the console.

---

This looks like useful data.  There are events called `depth`, `ticker`, and `trade`, with various kinds of associated fields.  I didn't read far enough into the documentation to know much about them, but if you're going to be working with this data, you should now be able to do something useful with this information stream.